# Elementary question about AGI and SS income

Tags: united-states, income-tax, social-security

I know that 15% of my social security income is not taxed at the Federal level.  But is that 15% a deduction or an adjustment?  That is, is the 15% counted in AGI or not?  I get gobbledegook when I google this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of social security income not subject to Federal income tax (at least 15%, but varying based on total base income) is not included in your AGI in normal annual filings.

On the current [form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf), total social security benefits are entered at the left on line 5a, while the taxable portion (85% or less) is entered at right in 5b per the worksheet on page 33 of [the instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf).  AGI is the sum of taxable income in the right hand column; lines 1, 2b, 3b, 4b, 5b, and adjustments from schedule 1.